# gsub, lookahead and lookbehind

Tags: r, regex

I have a string vector containing:

```
Number of source1.2_SPNB.txt
Number of source1.1_SPNB.txt
Number of source1.3_SPNB.txt
```

I need to extract "source1.1", "source1.2" and "source1.3" in a new vector.

Following [this](https://www.regexpal.com/96872), I tried:

```
gsub("(?<=of )(.*)(?=_)", "\\1", string.vector)
```

But I get an error:

> invalid regular expression '(?<=of )(.*)(?=_)', reason 'Invalid regexp'

I then tried:

```
gsub("(?<=of )(.*)(?=_)", "\\1", string.vector, perl = TRUE)
```

But it returned the exact same string vector.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several problems:

- perl = TRUE is needed to use lookahead/lookbehind
- even if we use that what the regular expression is doing is that it is just replacing the desired substring with itself --  what we want to do is match the entire string (as opposed to using zero width lookahead/lookbehind) and then replace the entire string with just the portion matching the capture group.
- there is presumably only one substitution required so `sub`, not `gsub`, should be used

Fixing these problems we get:

```
sub(".*(source.*?)_.*", "\\1", string.vector)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could match character until the space (`.*\\s`) or (`|`) a `_` followed by other characters (`.*`) and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
gsub(".*\\s|_.*", "", string.vector)
#[1] "source1.2" "source1.1" "source1.3"
```

Or if we need with capture groups, then

```
sub(".*\\sof\\s([^_]+).*", "\\1", string.vector)
#[1] "source1.2" "source1.1" "source1.3"
```

---

For extraction purpose, it may be better to use `str_extract` from `stringr` or the `regmatches/regexpr` from `base R`

```
regmatches(string.vector, regexpr("(?<=of )([^_]+)(?=_)", string.vector, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "source1.2" "source1.1" "source1.3"
```

#### data

```
string.vector <- c("Number of source1.2_SPNB.txt", "Number of source1.1_SPNB.txt", 
             "Number of source1.3_SPNB.txt")
```